# Why is my file output garbled?

Tags: c, file-io

When I read in a file and then output to a new file, the output is garbled, and I am trying to figure out why.

I am trying to run the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc ,char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    FILE *of;
    FILE *f;
    of=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(c=getc(f)!=EOF)
        putc(c,of);
    fclose(of);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;

 }
```

But when I run it as follows
`$./a.out temp new`

where `temp` is an existing file whose contents are:
`this is a temp file` and `new` doesn't exist before running the program

But now when I cat the contents of `new` it is all messed up why it is so?

Comment: Did you use the ```od``` or a different hexdump-style command to notice that every byte was Ctrl-A, ASCII 1?

Comment: Besides Daniel Fischer answer, consider to modify `main` to `int main`, to close with `fclose` and add `return 0` to return success from the main.

Comment: one more question arises i saw the octal dump of the file new but all bytes were not 1 the penultimate byte was 0 why was this so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
while(c=getc(f)!=EOF)
```

needs parentheses,

```
while( (c=getc(f)) != EOF)
```

the precedence of `!=` is higher than that of the assignment `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(c=getc(f)!=EOF)
        putc(c,of);
```

Let's see what your code does in the while loop; in the guard, you wrote

```
c=getc(f) !=EOF
```

The precedence of `!=` is higher than `=`, so what's really happening is

```
c=(getc(f) !=EOF)
```

, which means that you're writing in `of` a sequence of 1, i.e. `getc(f) != EOF`, until you find EOF.

What you meant to write, as already said, is probably

```
(c = getch(f)) != EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure if i'm right or not but don't you think that c should be a **char** and not an **int**?

Comment: If it's a `char` then all possible values are valid. How can you test for `EOF`?

Comment: Sakki, no, `EOF` is a negative integer (usually -1).

Comment: @Sakki: No. A file can contain zero bytes, so zero is perfectly valid. Also `getc` doesn't return a zero on end of file. To indicate the end of a file, you need some value that is *not* a legal character. And a character cannot contain a value that is not a legal character.

Comment: nice explanation. thanks daniel and david, this website is awesome LOTS of SKILLED and INTELLIGENT BRAINS here :)